# cannot read property 'id' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, reducers

i am currently React SPA application based on react-redux. in the reducer.js, I have two main states, which is mylist and recommendations. I have attached two picture of actually applicaion. there are two pages. first one is Home page which there are three initial recommendations of movies. under each movie there is a add button, which once you clicked the botton and the expectation is selected movie will be removed and will be added to second pages which is a mylist page.

on the mylist page, there will be three initial movie. there is a remove button underneath each movie, once i have clicked remove button, expectation is the selected movie is removed and will be added back to home page.

rightnow, i have implemented the add button, which once i clicked add button, the selected movie will be removed and will be add to mylist page.

the problem is in the mylist page once i clicked remove. the selected movie is removed but its not added to the home page.

Home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  handleClick = id => {
    this.props.addToList(id);
    this.props.removeFromRecom(id);
  };
  render() {
    let addedRecom1 = this.props.addedRecom.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
          <Image webP={item.img}></Image>
          <p style={{ marginLeft: "44px" }}>{item.title}</p>
          <button
            to="/"
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)}
            style={{
              marginLeft: "53px",
              paddingLeft: "10px",
              paddingRight: "10px",
              paddingTop: "0px",
              marginTop: "0px",
              marginBottom: "20px"
            }}
          >
            add
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavLink to="/myList" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <a
              style={{
                marginLeft: "378px",
                fontFamily: "Arial Black",
                color: "black",
                border: "solid 1px",
                backgroundColor: "orange",
                paddingLeft: "35px",
                paddingRight: "20px"
              }}
            >
              <i
                class="fa fa-plus"
                style={{ paddingRight: "10px", paddingLeft: "5px" }}
              ></i>
              My list
            </a>
          </NavLink>
          <p style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
            Recommendations
          </p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.recommendations.map(item => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id} style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
                <Image webP={item.img}></Image>
                <p style={{ marginLeft: "44px" }}>{item.title}</p>
                <button
                  to="/"
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: "53px",
                    paddingLeft: "10px",
                    paddingRight: "10px",
                    paddingTop: "0px",
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    marginBottom: "20px"
                  }}
                >
                  add
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {addedRecom1}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    addedRecom: state.addedRecom,
    recommendations: state.recommendations
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addToList: id => {
      dispatch(addToList(id));
    },
    removeFromRecom: id => {
      dispatch(removeFromRecom(id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

MyList.js

```
class MyList extends Component {
  handleRemoveMovie = id => {
    this.props.removeFromList(id);
    this.props.addToRecom(id);
  };
  render() {
    let addedMovies = this.props.addedMovies.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item.id} style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
          <Image webP={item.img}></Image>
          <p style={{ marginLeft: "44px" }}>{item.title}</p>
          <button
            to="myList"
            onClick={() => {
              this.handleRemoveMovie(item.id);
            }}
            style={{
              marginLeft: "53px",
              paddingLeft: "10px",
              paddingRight: "10px",
              paddingTop: "0px",
              marginTop: "0px",
              marginBottom: "20px"
            }}
          >
            remove
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavLink to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <a
              style={{
                marginLeft: "317px",
                fontFamily: "Arial Black",
                color: "black",
                border: "solid 1px",
                backgroundColor: "orange",
                paddingLeft: "28px",
                paddingRight: "20px"
              }}
            >
              <i
                class="fa fa-hand-o-left"
                style={{ paddingRight: "10px", paddingLeft: "5px" }}
              ></i>
              back to Home
            </a>
          </NavLink>
          <p style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginLeft: "20px" }}>My Lists</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.mylist.map(item => {
            return (
              <div key={item.id} style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
                <Image webP={item.img}></Image>
                <p style={{ marginLeft: "44px" }}>{item.title}</p>
                <button
                  to="myList"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.handleRemoveMovie(item.id);
                  }}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: "53px",
                    paddingLeft: "10px",
                    paddingRight: "10px",
                    paddingTop: "0px",
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    marginBottom: "20px"
                  }}
                >
                  remove
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {addedMovies}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    addedMovies: state.addedMovies,
    mylist: state.mylist
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    removeFromList: id => {
      dispatch(removeFromList(id));
    },
    addToRecom: id => {
      dispatch(addToRecom(id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyList);
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  mylist: [
    {
      title: "Futurama",
      id: 1,
      img: "http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/7621/3787621.webp"
    },
    {
      title: "The Interview",
      id: 2,
      img: "http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/1381/11971381.webp"
    },
    {
      title: "Gilmore Girls",
      id: 3,
      img: "http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/7451/11317451.webp"
    }
  ],
  recommendations: [
    {
      title: "Family Guy",
      id: 4,
      img: "http://cdn5.nflximg.net/webp/5815/2515815.webp"
    },
    {
      title: "The Croods",
      id: 5,
      img: "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/webp/2353/3862353.webp"
    },
    {
      title: "Friends",
      id: 6,
      img: "http://cdn0.nflximg.net/webp/3200/9163200.webp"
    }
  ],
  addedMovies: [],
  addedRecom: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === REMOVE_FROM_RECOM) {
    let Recom = state.recommendations.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
    return {
      ...state,
      recommendations: Recom
    };
  }

  if (action.type === ADD_TO_LIST) {
    let addedMovie = state.recommendations.find(item => item.id === action.id);
    let existed_movie = state.mylist;
    if (existed_movie) {
      return {
        ...state,
        addedMovies: [...state.addedMovies, addedMovie]
      };
    }
  }

  if (action.type === ADD_TO_RECOM) {
    let add_recom = state.mylist.find(item => item.id === action.id);
    let current_recom = state.recommendations;
    if (current_recom) {
      return {
        ...state,
        addedRecom: [...state.addedRecom, add_recom]
      };
    }
  }

  if (action.type === REMOVE_FROM_LIST) {
    let removedMovie = state.mylist.find(item => item.id === action.id);
    let newMovie = state.addedMovies.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
    return {
      ...state,
      addedMovies: newMovie
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};[![enter image description here][1]][1]

export default reducer;


TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/Home.js:17

  14 | render() {
  15 |   let addedRecom1 = this.props.addedRecom.map(item => {
  16 |     return (
> 17 |       <div key={item.id} style={{ float: "left", marginLeft: "20px" }}>
     | ^  18 |         <Image webP={item.img}></Image>
  19 |         <p style={{ marginLeft: "44px" }}>{item.title}</p>
  20 |         <button
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1] [image]

Comment: Let's make an update to your question. Let's edit it to clearly state what the problem is, what result you have, and what result you are expecting. Only include the relevant part of the code. This makes it easier to understand your issue and propose a solution.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is here `let add_recom = state.mylist.find(item => item.id === action.id);` If `add_recom` is undefined, it may throw that error.

Comment: I have edit again, sorry for the confusion, hope is clear this time @Ibu

Comment: thanks for the comment @Neil Chowdhury could that be something wrong about state.mylist?

Comment: use redux devtools and watch the store, or run `console.log(state.mylist)` before where you're getting the error to see what the problem is

Comment: @ZhunanShuai - please note that the error is about  `this.props.addedRecom`, you are trying to access `id` property of each item/s, where `item` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

In general you should have only two lists, one for `recommendations` and one for `myList`, and two reducers that handle deletion and addition of items from `myList`:

```
const initialState = {
    myList: [
        {
            title: 'Futurama',
            id: 1,
            img: 'http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/7621/3787621.webp'
        },
        {
            title: 'The Interview',
            id: 2,
            img: 'http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/1381/11971381.webp'
        },
        {
            title: 'Gilmore Girls',
            id: 3,
            img: 'http://cdn1.nflximg.net/webp/7451/11317451.webp'
        }
    ],
    recommendations: [
        {
            title: 'Family Guy',
            id: 4,
            img: 'http://cdn5.nflximg.net/webp/5815/2515815.webp'
        },
        {
            title: 'The Croods',
            id: 5,
            img: 'http://cdn3.nflximg.net/webp/2353/3862353.webp'
        },
        {
            title: 'Friends',
            id: 6,
            img: 'http://cdn0.nflximg.net/webp/3200/9163200.webp'
        }
    ]
};
```

Each reducer is incharge of updating both `recommendations` and `myList` upon deletion/addition of a movie:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD_TO_LIST') {
        let addToMyList = state.recommendations.find(item => item.id === action.id);
        return {
            ...state,
            myList: [ ...state.myList, addToMyList ],
            recommendations: state.recommendations.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
        };
    }

    if (action.type === 'REMOVE_FROM_LIST') {
        let removedItem = state.myList.find(item => item.id === action.id);
        return {
            ...state,
            myList: state.myList.filter(item => item.id !== action.id),
            recommendations: [ ...state.recommendations, removedItem ]
        };
    } else {
        return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```